# blur() vs. onblur()

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I have a input tag with an onblur event listener:

```
<input id="myField" type="input" onblur="doSomething(this)" />
```

Via JavaScript, I want to trigger the blur event on this input so that it, in turn, calls the `doSomething` function.

My initial thought is to call blur:

```
document.getElementById('myField').blur()
```

But that doesn't work (though no error).

This does:

```
document.getElementById('myField').onblur()
```

Why is that? `.click()` will call the click event attached to an element via the onclick listener. Why does `blur()` not work the same way?

Comment: I think blur() is jQuery and onBlur() is Javascript.

Comment: @Ray no, that's not really accurate, though it is true that jQuery provides a "blur" method to trigger an event (or register a handler). That method is supplied by jQuery objects, however, and is not available on plain DOM elements.

Comment: Although your question is answered but I am still curious what made you execute `doSomething()` function via explicitly triggering `onblur` function! Why could you not call `doSomething` directly?

Comment: @user1451111 my memory is a little fuzzy as to what I was doing 7 years ago :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This:

```
document.getElementById('myField').onblur();
```

works because your element (the `<input>`) has an attribute called "onblur" whose value is a function. Thus, you can call it.  You're **not** telling the browser to simulate the actual "blur" event, however; there's no event object created, for example.

Elements do not have a "blur" attribute (or "method" or whatever), so that's why the first thing doesn't work.

Comment: But you can call .click() to simulate a click event, correct? My mistake was assuming .blur() existed as well. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DA: `.blur()` does exist in some browsers, but you first need to give the element focus if it doesn't have it. [Try this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zYQqa/1/) in Chrome. I don't know which browsers do/don't support it.

Comment: Yes, because browsers **do** support a method on DOM elements called "click".  I agree that it's just not consistent; many of these things evolved quickly back 10 or more years ago before anybody had a chance to think much about synchronization. I think that's one of the main reasons that libraries like Prototype and jQuery are so popular.

Comment: What I wouldn't give for this project to be using jQuery... ;) So, if I stick with the onBlur() option, how (relatively) safe is that in terms of current browser support. Any gotcha's I should be looking for?

Comment: Well it's basically just accessing the reference to the function from the DOM element, so it's pretty safe.  I *think* IE will not complain about that and will correctly bind `this` to the element, but you might double-check that.

Comment: I think it makes sense that there is a click() but no blur(). To blur you will need to .focus() on another element - which is possible

Answer (score 12):

Contrary to what pointy says, the `blur()` method does exist and is a part of the [w3c standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025). The following exaple will work in every modern browser (including IE):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            window.onload = function()
            {
                var field = document.getElementById("field");
                var link = document.getElementById("link");
                var output = document.getElementById("output");

                field.onfocus = function() { output.innerHTML += "<br/>field.onfocus()"; };
                field.onblur = function() { output.innerHTML += "<br/>field.onblur()"; };
                link.onmouseover = function() { field.blur(); };
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="MyForm">
            <input type="text" name="field" id="field" />
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link">Blur field on hover</a>
            <div id="output"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that I used `link.onmouseover` instead of `link.onclick`, because otherwise the click itself would have removed the focus.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's just because the onblur event is called *as a result* of the input losing focus, there isn't a *blur* action associated with an input, like there is a *click* action associated with a button