# WebForms TextBox Lost Focus Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add an event handler to a `TextBox` control that is called when the text box loses focus. Is this possible?

I know WinForms has a `LostFocus` event. I'm looking for something similar in ASP.NET WebForms.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use `OnBlur`

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur="Javascript:alert('1234');" />
```

Or 
EDIT:
Server side

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onblur", "alert('hi User')");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to call C# code at all with this method?

Comment: @rar you can add your server side code (C#) with above

Comment: Do you mean add the JavaScript server side, or is there a way to add C# code to the onblur event?

Comment: If You want to Execute Something From Server Side then You can take One asp Button Make it display none and call its postback event onblur of textbox

Comment: The server side solution doesn't seem to work if I want to add text from another page element.

Comment: if You Wants to Display Some Text from another Page Then You have to Maintain State at Server Side http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492397/State-Management-in-ASP-NET-Introduction

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to use javascript for this and the event you will need to search and look up would be onBlur() I believe. If you need an example, I might be able to scrounge one up for you. But here are some links..

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

[Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212651/blur-vs-onblur)

[Java Page](http://javascript.info/tutorial/focus-blur)

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the `blur` event, and it's a client-side event on the resulting `input` element instead of a server-side event on the `TextBox` control.

For example, let's say you have a `TextBox` with the `ID` of "TextBox1", and let's assume jQuery is included in your project template (because it probably is), then in your client-side code you might have something like this:

```
$('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
    // code to respond to the event
});
```

This would execute any code in that function whenever the `input` for that `TextBox` control loses focus.  Notice the use of a small block of server-side code to output the server-side control's client-side ID.