# Other text input methods?

Tags: c#, geckofx

There are a bunch of websites with "search" input boxes.
If I input a word manually then it automatically search without need to click any buttons.

Using the following code:

```
             GeckoInputElement input = (GeckoInputElement)geckoHtmlElement;
             input.Value = "searchword";
```

The I see that search input box is filled but nothing happens automatically.
If I manually add space or any character then website works as expected.
Auto searches my wanted word.

I tried using input.Focus();   but still same.
Any ideas how I can input text into search box in a more advanced way or something like that?

Comment: You appear to be using serverside code to fill the element. The code needed for doing this kind of stuff has to be on the clientside

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. Didnt knew how to explain. Any idea how to make it clientise that It could work as I input text manually?

Comment: Perhaps causing a "blur" will work. Either call it directly, or move the focus elsewhere to force a blur event. This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212651/blur-vs-onblur

Comment: aHH I'm not sure if you understood what Im asking for. Im making automation on geckofx browser and I need way to input text fields proper way which would trigger any javascripts or something which are on that webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution here is to manually trigger the event that triggers the search - for example the keyup event. I had the same problem which I solved by adding this code:

```
    nsAStringBase eventType = (nsAStringBase)new nsAString("keyup");
            var ev = browser.Document.CreateEvent("HTMLEvents");
            ev.DomEvent.InitEvent(eventType, false, false);
nameBox.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);
```

You would need to inspect your page and see if there are any javascript events attached to your input.
Good luck!